# Removing int value in dynamic array and setting it to NULL

Tags: c++

So my code is suppose to insert numbers into a dynamic array, add more capacity to the array if more is needed, remove numbers from the array and then make sure the only NULLS occur at the end of the array. It also tells the user how many numbers are in the array and what is the total size of the array. My problem is when I remove a number from the array, it sometimes prints out there is a number -33686019 in my array. This doesn't occur much, but I don't want it to occur at all.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

int* gArray = NULL;
int gSize = 0;
int gCapacity = 0;
void Insert(int value);
void Remove(int value);
void Resize(int newCapacity);
void Print(void);


void main()
{
int input = 0;

while(input != 3)
{
    printf(">=== Dynamic Array ===\n");
    printf("What do you want to do?\n");
    printf("1. Insert\n");
    printf("2. Remove\n");
    printf("3. Quit\n");
    printf("Your choice: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &input);
    printf("\n\n");

    int value = 0;

    switch(input)
    {
    case 1:
        {
            printf("Enter a number: ");
            scanf_s("%d", &value);
            Insert(value);
            Print();
            break;
        }
    case 2:
        {
            printf("Enter number you wish to delete: ");
            scanf_s("%d", &value);
            Remove(value);
            Print();
            break;
        }
    case 3:
        {
            break;
        }
    default:
        {
            printf("Invalid selection\n");
        }
    }
}
}
void Insert(int value)
{
bool valueSet = false;

while(valueSet == false)
{
    if(gArray == NULL)
    {
        Resize(1);
        gArray[gSize] = value;
        ++gSize;
        valueSet = true;
    }
    else if(gArray[gCapacity] == NULL)
    {
        gArray[gSize] = value;
        ++gSize;
        valueSet = true;
    }
    else if(gArray[gCapacity] != NULL)
    {
        Resize((gCapacity + 1));
        gArray[gSize] = value;
        ++gSize;
        valueSet = true;
    }
}

}
void Resize(int newCapacity)
{
int* tempArray = new int[newCapacity];
std::copy(gArray, gArray+(newCapacity-1), tempArray);
gArray = new int[newCapacity];
std::copy (tempArray, tempArray+(newCapacity-1), gArray);
gCapacity = newCapacity;
}
void Remove(int value)
{
for(int i = 0; i < gCapacity; ++i)
{
    if(gArray[i] == value)
    {
        gArray[i] = NULL;
        --gSize;
    }
}
for(int i = 0; i < gCapacity; ++i)
{
    if(gArray[i] == NULL)
    {
        gArray[i] = gArray[(i + 1)];
        gArray[(i + 1)] = NULL;
    }
}
}
void Print(void)
{
printf("Array contains: ");
for(int i = 0; i < gCapacity; ++i)
{
    if(gArray[i] != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d, ", gArray[i]);
    }
}
printf("size = %d, capacity = %d\n", gSize, gCapacity);


}
```

Comment: Is this an assignment? `std::vector` is designed for this.

Comment: First of all, the concept of `NULL` is only suited to pointers. There is no such thing as a null `int`, and what you are doing is (probably) setting `ints` to `0`. Second, is this an assignment or exercise, and is so, are you not allowed to use the C++ standard library?

Comment: Since this is c++: Whats with the manual memory management? `std::vector` would do a better job.

Comment: @juanchopanza std::copy is also a part of the standard library...

Comment: @IgorR. Thanks, I missed that. It was too far down. Presumably all the code could be replaced with a standard library container and an algorithm or two, which is why I was asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concrete problem is that you don't initialize the new array (resp. `tempArray`) in your `Resize` function.

When calling

```
int* tempArray = new int[newCapacity];
```

the array can contain arbitrary values. Only `newCapacity-1` values are copied from the old array, so the last value is undefined. It might be 0 but haven't to be. Use

```
std::fill(tempArray, tempArray+newCapacity, 0);
```

to initialize your array with zero.

Apart from that, there are a few other problems:

- You don't delete the old array before allocating a new one. Use `delete[] gArray` for that. Also `tempArray`isn't deleted!
- You don't need to copy the values twice. Just to a `gArray = tempArray` (after deleting the old `gArray`, see above)
- You assume that `newCapacity` is just larger by one than `gCapacity` (you copy `newCapacity-1` values from the old array). It would be better to copy `gCapacity` values instead.
- Dynamic arrays which only grow by one are inefficient, since adding a value takes linear time (you have to copy all the old values when inserting a single one). Usually, you double the size of the array every time you run out of space, this gives constant insertion time in average.
- NULL is normally used only for pointers. For ints it is equal to zero which means, you cannot store `0` in your array (given your requirements)
- In production code, I'd  *strongly* recommend using `std::vector` instead of any home-grown solution.

**EDIT**

See @StackUnderflows answer for what is probably the real cause of the error. If you run in Debug mode, some compilers will automatically initialize the array for you, which might be the ccase here.

The `gArray[i]=gArray[i+1]` line in your `Remove` function is definitely wrong on the other hand, since it accesses a value which is beyond the limits of the array.

Answer (score 2):

An option, since you are using the c++ standard library would be to remove all your code, and use [std::list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) and its `insert` and `remove` methods. If you require the data to be in a dynamic array, then use [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and the [erase remove](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom) idiom for removal.

I have to point out that, since your question is "*Removing int value in dynamic array and setting it to NULL*", that setting an int to `NULL` is essentially setting it to the value `0`, since `NULL` tends to be a define for `0`. So if your list were to contain zeroes, this setting to `NULL` and checking for equality with `NULL` would completely break the logic of your algorithm. C++11 has `nullptr`, an actual null type that cannot be assigned to an int, to deal with this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs on the last iteration in the second loop of `Remove` when you do `gArray[i] = gArray[i + 1]`. On the last iteration, `gArray[i + 1]` is actually one past the end of your array, so you are now in undefined behavior territory. You are assigning this undefined value to the last element `gArray[i]`.

---

I suggest using `std::vector<int>` instead. It manipulates an array under the hood which grows/resizes for you as you add more elements.

Comment: I missed this one, which is most probably the real cause. There were just so many other oddities in the code ...